# Can the holder of only a Commerical Balloon pilot certificate conduct the ground training for a "Flight Review" for Airplane only rated pilots?

Tags: faa-regulations, balloon, currency, logbook-endorsements, ground-instructor

In the U.S., since there is not a Certified Flight Instructor (CFI) rating for "lighter-than-air" category pilots, someone who holds *only* a **Commercial** Balloon pilot certificate can provide the flight and ground training and various endorsements in order for someone to become a balloon pilot. [14 CFR 61.133(a)(2)(ii)(D)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.133(a)(2)(i)(E))

**Question**:

Can the holder of a "Balloon" *only* Commercial Pilot certificate conduct and provide the endorsement for the 1 hour (minimum) of **ground training** required for a [14 CFR 61.56(a)(1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.56(a)) Flight Review for a pilot who holds, for example, an Airline Transport Pilot certificate and is only rated in Airplanes?

Of course the **flight training** portion of the Flight Review would have to be conducted by an instructor who holds an "Airplane" rating on his/her CFI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.  They cannot provide ground training for a flight review in any other category aircraft.**

The full text of the CFR cited above:

> (2) Commercial pilots with lighter-than-air category ratings.  A person with a commercial pilot certificate with a lighter-than-air category rating may -
>
> > (ii) **For a balloon**  -
> >
> > > (A) Give flight and ground training in a balloon for the issuance of a certificate or rating;
> > >
> > > (B) Give an endorsement for a pilot certificate with a balloon rating;
> > >
> > > (C) Endorse a pilot's logbook for solo operating privileges in a balloon; and
> > >
> > > (D) Give ground and flight training and endorsements that are required for a flight review, an operating privilege, or recency-of-experience requirements of this part.

The regulation is specific to an (1) airship or a (2) balloon classes.

If a holder of a commercial balloon category certificate wanted to provide ground instruction for an airplane category flight review they will need to become a ground instructor per [§61.215](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-I/section-61.215)

Comment: Thanks.  But would you agree that If the ATP airplane pilot (in my question)  also held a Private pilot rating in a Hot Air Balloon the Commercial Pilot rated only in Balloons could give not only the ground training but also the flight training required for a 61.56 Flight Review in a Balloon that would also count for the ATP Pilot's 61.56 currency in an airplane. (Good idea or not)

Comment: Yes.  I would agree with that comment.  It is legal as it satisfies the requirement for a flight review.  Is it a good idea?  Maybe.  Imagine a pilot who flies his airplane all the time and only balloons occasionally.  Getting a flight review in a balloon would be a fantastic idea.

Comment: Almost ready to accept your answer,  but still pondering and doing some more research.  Sub-para (d) in your answer (the actual reg) says "...recency-of-experience...of this *part* which is the entirety of part 61.  Not a big difference between what I  said in my comment and having a Balloon only "authorized instructor" do the ground training.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are missing part of the regulation in 61.56(c)(1).  "Accomplished a flight review given in an aircraft for which that **pilot is rated** by an authorized instructor".  If the pilot receiving the flight review doesn't have a balloon rating a balloon instructor cannot provide the required ground training unless they also have a basic or advanced ground instructor certificate.

Comment: I don't disagree.  But the (c) (1) was written in a context that seems to assume the ground and flight review are done by the same person.  The ground part is not "...given in an aircraft..." That is why, I believe a non-pilot ground instructor (by regulation) can give the ground portion.  But, you are likely correct.